# Why has the proportion of women in computer science degrees declined in the USA?

Tags: academia

[image: Percentage of Bachelor's degrees conferred to women in the U.S.A., by major (1970-2012)]
[Source](http://www.randalolson.com/2014/06/14/percentage-of-bachelors-degrees-conferred-to-women-by-major-1970-2012/)

In the United States, for most majors, the proportion of women either increased or stayed static. By contrast, the proportion of women in computer science declined from a peak of 37% in 1983 to now being in the high teens. What caused this decline?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a question about the history of science; it may be more of a sociological question. Perhaps we could have a discussion about it, either in chat or on meta. In particular, I think it may be a better fit for [academics.se]

Comment: I have a hunch this effect can be partly traced back to China.

Comment: Is this really a question about history of science and math?

Comment: I share the sentiment about this possibly being off site topic as a question, but something tells me there may be a historical answer if one can address the sharp trend from about 1970 to 1982.

Comment: I would like to remind you all that, if you think this question is off-topic, it is encouraged that you vote to close (I'm not saying you should vote, I'm saying you should vote *if* you think it's off-topic). This type of community moderation is vital to the SE-model.

Comment: @J.W.Perry That would actually be incredibly easy question to answer if you were to restrict attention to just CS degrees being obtained from Caltech and MIT. 1970 was "the year the aliens invaded", when Caltech first opened admissions to females. MIT followed suit the next year. This spike in female admittance then naturally leads to a spike in female degree recipients 4-5 years later. ;)